# How can I make an atomic transfer of funds to multiple recipients on NEAR, using the Rust SDK?

Tags: rust, transactions, rollback, nearprotocol

I have a funds-distribution contract in Rust.  It has a single payable API method that takes a vector of NEAR Account IDs (`payees`), and attempts to split the payment evenly between that list of recipients.  The essential subroutine is this:

```rust
    fn transfer_to_each(&self, payees: Vec<AccountId>, sum: Balance) -> Promise {
        // pay each payee in a loop
        let promises: Vec<Promise> = payees.into_iter().map(|p| {
            Promise::new(p.to_string()).transfer(sum)
        } ).collect();

        // boil all those promises down into a super-promise
        let mut big_p = promises[0].clone();
        for pi in 1..promises.len() {
            big_p = big_p.and(promises[pi].clone());
        }

        // return the final promise
        big_p
    }
```

When this runs, if any of the provided AccountIds don't actually exist as accounts, the promise for that ID aborts, and then the final promise created by Promise.and() also aborts.  I think that's correct behavior.

The trouble is, the funds are not returned to the pre-transaction state after the transaction fails.  All of the legitimate accounts receive a transfer, but the remaining funds remain in the distribution contract itself.

[The NEAR documentation seems to say that transactions on the chain are atomic, unless they use function calls](https://docs.near.org/docs/concepts/transaction#atomicity).  Or, to be more NEAR-specific, my final Promise should create a Receipt that will be applied atomically.  But when that receipt fails, there's no rollback. So maybe receipts created with Promise.and() are not atomic either?

Is it even possible to make this transaction atomically with the NEAR+Rust SDK?  Or are atomic transactions only possible inside a single shard?

EDIT: The first responder pointed out the Batch Promise API for ActionScript, but I can't find an example of how to use that from Rust.  Also, it looks like a batch promise can't transfer funds to more than one user.

Comment: FYI I've confirmed the same behavior on testnet.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to do Atomicity (all work or none work) on the chain, but I think iterating over a list is not the right way to do this. That's why Promises that resolve (OK) actually transfers funds, and the one(s) that fail(s) don't. Failed transactions will not stop execution (why would they?) of the successful ones. Again, you're trying to do Atomicity (as in SQL?).

Have you checked out cross-contract and the Batch promise API?
https://github.com/near-examples/cross-contract-calls/tree/main/contracts/00.orientation

Comment: Hmm okay. The NEAR docs do promise that all Transactions have Atomicity baked in (except for Function Call Transactions), but I guess each promise I create in a contract is a separate Transaction. The promise from promise.and() clearly doesn't have Atomicity either.

Comment: In your link there's this `foxy_proxy` example that's just about exactly what I'm trying to do. But it's still having to create multiple promises to send funds to multiple users, because a Batch promise seems to only be able to act on one account.  But maybe with this API everything magically becomes a single transaction somehow.  I'll test it!